# Postgres syntax error with INSERT into TableFoo SELECT from TableFoo.

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

Postgres 8.1 on linux.

When I try:

```
   insert into card(
                    routine_id, page, row, col, show_card, flip_card
                 )
                    select (
                        999, 0, 0, 0, show_card, flip_card
                    ) from card   WHERE
                        routine_id = 89 AND page = 0  AND row = 0  AND col = 0
                ;
```

I get:

```
ERROR:  column "routine_id" is of type integer but expression is of type record
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

The select gives back a single column called "row record" that looks like this: (999,0,0,0,1,0)

Googling suggests that my syntax is SQL correct, perhaps this is a Postgres deviation??

Comment: This doesn't directly affect your issue, but:
8.1 is obsolete and unsupported; in fact, the end-of-life announcement for 8.2 was sent today, so you're two releases behind the supported version and FIVE behind the current version. You should look at updating to at least 8.3 or preferably 9.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the parentheses after the SELECT.

```
INSERT INTO card
    (routine_id, page, row, col, show_card, flip_card)
    SELECT 999, 0, 0, 0, show_card, flip_card
        FROM card   
        WHERE routine_id = 89 AND page = 0  AND row = 0  AND col = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

eliminate the brackets around the select portion:

```
insert into card (routine_id, page, row, col, show_card, flip_card)
    select 999, 0, 0, 0, show_card, flip_card
    from card
    WHERE routine_id = 89 AND page = 0  AND row = 0  AND col = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that putting the parenthesis enclosing your columns make Postgres treat it as a 'row record'. I'd imagine that removing the parenthesis will make it work since the result set will just be a list of separate columns with values